# Date saving incorrectly to database only randomly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a form creating bookings that seems to only occasionally bring the date back incorrectly. For example if you had 01/12/17, it is being recognised and saved as as 17/12/01. Now this isn't all bookings just a few. I was thinking it might be to do with the fact that it is taken in the form as a string and turned into a date when it is being created.

It seems to be happening to random people on the live site but have yet to see any happen on my localhost.

The reason it is as: :string is for the datepicker being used. Which doesn't let you type in dates you choose from a dropdown calendar.

Is there something I am missing here or if anyone has any ideas of things I can try? Any help that would be greatly appreciated.

Part of the form that deals with the date:

```
<%= simple_form_for [:cms, venue, booking] do |f| %>
  ...
  <fieldset class="form-group">
      <%=f.input :date, label: "Date of booking",as: :string, wrapper: :pikaday %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Here is the create method:

```
def create
 @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
  if booking_params[:reference_1] == '' || booking_params[:reference_2] == ''
    flash[:error] = 'Must fill in both parts of booking reference'
    return render :new
  else
    @booking.reference_number(booking_params)
  end
 if @booking.save
   flash[:notice] = 'Booking created and e-mail to organiser sent!'
   redirect_to cms_venue_path(venue)
 else
   flash[:error] = 'Please review the errors and try again'
   render :new
 end
end
```

In database as date:

```
 create_table "bookings", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
      t.date "date"
      ...
    end
```

I also found this pikaday code:

```
new Pikaday({
  field: document.getElementById('datepicker')
  , format: 'D/M/YYYY'
  , minDate: new Date()
});
```

Comment: Why is your field input for `date` a `string`? This is obviously the source of the problem.

Comment: Your date format is ambiguous. Try to pass the date as `2017-12-01` (ISO 8601). Your date picker probably allows you to set the format.

Comment: I don't know exactly what's causing the coercion issue -- it could be user error (e.g. entering dates in mm/dd/yyyy format), or browser configuration (if using a datepicker, maybe the browser's locale is choosing the format), or maybe something in your backend (is `booking_params` parsing the date based on the user's locale?)....

Comment: ...But no matter where the offensive line of code lies, fix the problem at the source. **Never** accept ambiguous dates inputted as free-text fields, if you can avoid it.

Comment: The reason it is as: :string is for the datepicker being used. Which doesn't let you type in dates you choose from a dropdown calendar.

Comment: @Georgeheap OK, but you can: (1) make the field disabled, and (2) force datepicker to use a specific locale for date format.

Comment: Or, use a different datepicker!

Answer (score 0):

Date parsing might be issue.just create an initializer 
in config/initializers/date_time.rb

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%d/%m/%Y"
```

Answer (score 0):

Users are probably in different countries where they express dates differently. In America we do MM-DD-YYYY, but in most of Europe they do DD-MM-YYYY and I don't know directly, but I bet there are some that do other stuff.

```
<%= simple_form_for [:cms, venue, booking] do |f| %>
  ...
  <fieldset class="form-group">
      <%=f.input :date, label: "Date of booking (DD-MM-YYYY)",as: :string, wrapper: :pikaday %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

The easiest solution would be to specify in parenthesis that the format you want it in is (DD-MM-YYYY) and the other thing you could do is with assuming the format based on Localization of the user.

```
<%= simple_form_for [:cms, venue, booking] do |f| %>
  ...
  <fieldset class="form-group">
      <%=f.input :date, label: "Date of booking",as: :date, wrapper: :pikaday %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Putting it in as: :date breaks the datepicker we are using.

Comment: *"In America we do DD-MM-YYYY, but in most of Europe they do MM-DD-YYYY"* ... It's the other way around!

Comment: That was a pre-coffee answer <3 thanks for pointing that out @TomLord